# Forms authentication not logging in with correct credentials

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, authentication

I am trying to configure forms authentication to password protect a folder. it is currenty not logging in any user even if credentials are correct.

Here is my code...

Web Config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="999999">
    <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
      <user name="admin" password="passwordhashhere" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

then outside the last system.web:

```
<location path="Admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="admin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

then in my aspx:

```
<div class="user">
    <p>Username:</p>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class="pass">
    <p>Password:</p>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class="login">   
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonLogin" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
    <asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Then in my codebehind:

```
Protected Sub ButtonLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogin.Click
    If Membership.ValidateUser(TextBoxUser.Text, TextBoxPass.Text) Then
        If Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl") IsNot Nothing Then
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBoxUser.Text, False)
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TextBoxUser.Text, False)
        End If
    Else
        LabelError.Text = "Invalid UserID and Password"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<deny users="?" />
```

instead of `<deny users="*" />` in your second code block...

and also

```
<allow users="*" />
```

instead of `<allow users="?" />` in  first code block or its not required..